# TripleDES Encryption in java for decryption in C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, tripledes

I have C# code which decrypts encrypted token passed by another application. I can not change this part.
Now i'm writing an application in java which will encrypt my token, that would be passed to C# application.

I'm not able to match encrypted string with java code. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

> C# Code

```cs
public class Crypto
{
    private TripleDES DesInstance = null;

    public Crypto(string key)
    {
        byte[] password = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(key);
        DesInstance = new System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, null);
        DesInstance.IV = new byte[8];
        DesInstance.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, DesInstance.IV);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string cipheredText)
    {
        byte[] cipherText = StringToByteArray(cipheredText);
        string plainText = null;

        ICryptoTransform transform = DesInstance.CreateDecryptor();

        MemoryStream memStreamEncryptedData = new MemoryStream(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length - 1);
        CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(memStreamEncryptedData, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(encStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
        {
            plainText = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return plainText;
    }

    private byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }
}
```

> Java Code

```java
public class TripleDes {

    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF-8";
    public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";
    private KeySpec ks;
    private SecretKeyFactory skf;
    private Cipher cipher;
    byte[] arrayBytes;
    private String myEncryptionKey;
    private String myEncryptionScheme;
    SecretKey key;

    public TripleDes() throws Exception {
        myEncryptionKey = "045e466ccc34a1f1688640d0441601b7ae2c";
        myEncryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
        arrayBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        ks = new DESedeKeySpec(arrayBytes);
        skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        key = skf.generateSecret(ks);
    }

    public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            encryptedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedText));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
        String decryptedText = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText = new String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `myEncryptionKey` the same as the string being passed to the `Crypto` constructor?

Comment: @JimRhodes Does it matter if no attempt is even made to implement `PasswordDeriveBytes`? Note that that is basically PBKDF1, but with "special" Microsoft code to extend it if the result is larger than the hash, in this case SHA-1. Special in the sense that it is entirely insecure and **should** be replaced directly.

Comment: The C# code does not use the algorithm based on PBKDF1 extended by MS, but the algorithm from MS CAPI's `CryptoDeriveKey()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# code uses `PasswordDeriveBytes#CryptDeriveKey()` as key derivation function which is a wrapper around CAPI's `CryptDeriveKey()` function (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/shawnfa/generating-a-key-from-a-password)). This functionality is missing in the Java code and is one of the reasons for the incompatibility.

`PasswordDeriveBytes#CryptDeriveKey()` is not to be confused with `PasswordDeriveBytes#GetBytes()`. The latter uses the (by MS) extended implementation of the PBKDF1 algorithm mentioned in the comments, which is not applied here.

The algorithm of `CryptDeriveKey()` is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptderivekey) and an implementation can be found [here](https://www.databasedevelop.com/article/11530018/Java+version+of+MS+CryptDeriveKey()):

```java
public static byte[] CryptDeriveKey(byte[] hBaseData, String hashAlgorithm, int requiredLength) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    int keyLength = hBaseData.length;
    byte[] derivedKey = new byte[requiredLength];
    if (keyLength >= requiredLength) {
        for (int i = 0; i < requiredLength; i++) {
            derivedKey[i] = hBaseData[i];
        }
        return derivedKey;
    }

    byte[] buff1 = new byte[64];
    byte[] buff2 = new byte[64];
    Arrays.fill(buff1, (byte) 0x36);
    Arrays.fill(buff2, (byte) 0x5C);
    for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) {
        buff1[i] ^= hBaseData[i];
        buff2[i] ^= hBaseData[i];
    }

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
    md.reset();
    byte[] result1 = md.digest(buff1);
    md.reset();
    byte[] result2 = md.digest(buff2);

    for (int i = 0; i < requiredLength; i++) {
        if (i < result1.length)
            derivedKey[i] = result1[i];
        else
            derivedKey[i] = result2[i - result1.length];
    }
    return derivedKey;
}
```

Note that `CryptDeriveKey()` does not expect the passphrase as first parameter, but the hash of the passphrase.

Example of usage:

```java
String passphrase = "my passphrase";
String digestName = "SHA-1"; 
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestName);
byte[] hash = md.digest(passphrase.getBytes("Cp1252"));
byte[] key = CryptDeriveKey(hash, digestName, 24);
System.out.println(HexFormat.of().formatHex(key)); // 5de508082bfe0924356d881c8cde15a540c92f267ef5a416
```

Note that in the case of DES or TripleDES the parity bits are not adjusted. This happens implicitly in `SecretKeyFactory#generateSecret()`.

---

Additional issues: Apart from key derivation, the CBC mode with a zero IV, PKCS#7 padding and the appropriate encodings for plaintext (Cp1252) and ciphertext (hex encoding) are to be used in the Java code. Since the C# code removes the last byte of the ciphertext for unknown reasons, a dummy byte must be added to the end of the ciphertext in the Java code.

Although the C# code can not be changed according to the description, the following notes on vulnerabilities: The key derivation is weak (this applies to both `CryptDeriveKey()` and PBKDF1) and should be replaced by a dedicated password-based key derivation like Argon2 or PBKDF2. A static IV (like a zero IV) is also weak. TripleDES is deprecated and slow and should be replaced with a modern algorithm like AES.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco. I am able to encrypt in java and decrypt in C# and data matches. However, if my input string contains extended ASCII characters (for ex. Latin small letter y with acute- ý), that's returning some incorrect character in place of that. What do you suggest, why it happens that way.

Comment: @MahendraSingh, your C# code is using `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(key)` but your Java code uses `myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UTF-8)`.

Comment: @MahendraSingh - This is probably due to the different encodings of the plaintext, which I addressed in the second section. The C# code uses Cp1252, while the Java code uses UTF-8. You must also use Cp1252 in the Java code if the C# code is not allowed to be changed.